# How to get Youtube videos uploaded since a particular date, with view count, in a particular location using youtube data api?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get Youtube videos uploaded since a particular date, with view count, in a particular location using youtube data api. Is there a way to get this data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the [YouTube API endpoint Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) and use the 'publishedAfter', 'location', and 'locationRadius' parameters.

After getting the snippet results you'll have to take the videoIDs and then make batch requests to the [Videos: list endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) to get the statistics, which has the view count.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can get the view count of a specific video by using the [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list). Just use `statistics` as your `part` parameter.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=6cKspfdDWZI&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

If you want a particular date or with a date range, you cannot do it with the YouTube Data API. The only thing that can get the view count with date range is the [YouTube Analytics and Reporting APIs.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/).

However, this API is only for a [channel view count](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reference/reports/query#try-it), not a specific video.

Hope it helps you.